# append pandas.DataFrame.GroupBy results into another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I'm analyzing the google ngram database which can be downloaded here:
http://storage.googleapis.com/books/ngrams/books/datasetsv2.html

It's a tab-separated file. It has no header, and the data look like this.

```
financial analysis       2000    3       3       1
financial analysis       2002    2       2       1
financial analysis       2004    1       1       1
financial analysis       2005    4       4       3
financial analysis       2006    10      10      7
financial analysis       2007    47      37      17
financial analysis       2008    63      54      31
financial capacity       1899    1       1       1
financial capacity       1997    2       2       2
financial capacity       1998    4       4       2
financial capacity       1999    3       3       3
financial capacity       2000    4       2       2
financial capacity       2003    1       1       1
financial capacity       2004    4       4       3
financial capacity       2005    2       2       2
financial capacity       2006    2       2       2
financial capacity       2007    26      24      17
financial capacity       2008    26      25      19
financial straits        1998    2       2       2
financial straits        1999    1       1       1
financial straits        2000    1       1       1
financial straits        2002    3       3       3
financial straits        2004    1       1       1
financial straits        2005    6       6       6
financial straits        2006    8       8       6
financial straits        2007    8       8       8
financial straits        2008    23      23      20
```

What I'm trying to do is make a dataframe that only keeps the sum of the counts(the column after year) regardless of the year.
So what I want is some thing like this:

```
financial analysis    110
financial capacity    75
financial straits     53
```

Below is what I tried. The raw data is spread among 100 files so it begins with a for-loop.

```
import pandas as pd
import zipfile

df_ngram = pd.DataFrame(columns=['ngram','count'])
### read files from 0 to 99, open csv in chunks to avoid memory error
for i in range(1):
    z = zipfile.ZipFile("googlebooks-eng-all-2gram-20090715-"+str(i)+".csv.zip")
    reader = pd.read_csv(z.open("googlebooks-eng-all-2gram-20090715-"+str(i)+".csv"), deli$

    ### iterate over chunks and aggregate data
    for chunk in reader:
            agg_chunk = chunk.groupby(['ngram'])['count'].sum()
            print agg_chunk.head(5)
            df_ngram.append(agg_chunk)
            print df_ngram.tail(5)
```

I used groupby to aggregate my dataframe, and tried to save the results in another dataframe(df_ngram). But it seems like it isn't appending at all. Below is what I get when I run this. I'm not sure how to deal with the groupby results. How can I aggregate the results from groupby? Or can I get what I want without using groupby?

```
ngram
"warmongers           5339
"warns               55904
"warplanes            4939
"warranlo              181
"warrantizabimus       107
Name: count, dtype: int64
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [ngram, count]
Index: []
ngram
"wildbores          65
"wildebeest      12003
"wildlooking       318
"wilfnlness         52
"wilrde             79
Name: count, dtype: int64
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [ngram, count]
Index: []
ngram
"Évora           155
"Österreichs     507
"Übers           159
"échappent        84
"égal            537
Name: count, dtype: int64
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [ngram, count]
Index: []
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to append the intermediate DataFrames to a list and then concatenate the results.

Before your `for` loop, add `df_agg = list()`.

Instead of `df_ngram.append(agg_chunk)`, you want `df_agg.append(agg_chunk)`

Finally, at the very end and outside of the loop, you want:

```
df_ngram = pd.concat(df_agg, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: I did `df_ngram = pd.concat(df_agg, ignore_index=True)` but then `print df_ngram.head(10)` gives me `0     279
1     143
2      40
3     102
4      49
5      51
6    1501
7     208
8    1302
9     812
Name: count, dtype: int64` which isn't what I wanted. I want the dataframe indexes to be my ngrams not index numbers. Setting `ignore_index=False` also doesn't work. And I want to set the column names to ['ngram', 'count'], but this can be done in separate line.

Comment: I'm confused.  Your comments indicated that my recommendations didn't work, yet you marked it as the accepted answer. Can you please clarify?

Comment: My fault. Setting `ignore_index=False` gave me what I wanted, but the raw data had something I didn't expected so I thought it didn't work. Thanks!